# Angular watch element height in directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to do something like this:

index.html

```
<div ng-controller="MyController" menu>
    <input ng-model="myVar"/>
    <div slimscroll="{'height':menuheight,'alwaysVisible':true}">
        <div id="menucontent" menu-content>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When there is text in the in the input field, it will perform filtering on `menu-content` directive. As it filter, the height of `menu-content` change.

Menu Directive:

```
angular.directive('menu', function(){
    return function (scope, element) {
        var menuContentHeight = $("#menucontent").height();
        scope.menuContentHeight = function(){
            return $("#menucontent").height();
        };

        scope.$watch(scope.menuContentHeight, function(newValue, oldValue) {
            if (newValue !== oldValue) {
                console.log('Changed!');
                menuContentHeight = newValue;
                adjustHeight();
            }
        },true);

        function adjustHeight(){
            // Perform height adjustment
        }
    };
});
```

So, what I am trying to do is use `scope.watch` to monitor the height change and do the update. My code does works, but the problem is it doesn't update instantly.

How can I get the height adjustment update instantly as soon as the height is changed?

Answer (score 0):

use $scope.apply()

```
scope.$watch(scope.menuContentHeight, function(newValue, oldValue) {
            if (newValue !== oldValue) {
                console.log('Changed!');
                menuContentHeight = newValue;
                adjustHeight();
                $scope.apply();  //call digest cycle
            }
        },true);
```

It may help for u...

Comment: Tried with that. The problem is not with call digest cycle. I guess is the scope.$watch thing because as soon as it update the view it console log out the message.]